# SharedPreferences not keeping value

Tags: java, android, load, save, sharedpreferences

With SharedPreferences, i would like to save a value (that will be later the date of last update) and load it. It works well until i shut down my phone or force close my application. It resets the value.

Here's the code :

```
public class feedPlayer extends Activity 
{
    public final static String PARAM_USERDETAILS="userdetails";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 

        loadvars();
        savevars();
    }

    public void savevars()
    {
        SharedPreferences parametres = this.getSharedPreferences(PARAM_USERDETAILS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor edit = parametres.edit();
        edit.clear();

        //Global.Maj = "maj"

        TextView maj=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.datemaj);
        edit.putString("gimli", Global.MAJ);
        edit.commit();
        maj.setText(Global.MAJ);
    }

    public void loadvars()
    {
        SharedPreferences parametres = this.getSharedPreferences(PARAM_USERDETAILS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        TextView maj=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.datemaj);
        String Smaj = parametres.getString("gimli", Global.MAJ);

        maj.setText(Smaj);
    }
}
```

Comment: try calling loadvars in onPause method?

Comment: A copy paste of your code worked fine for me in emulator (even after force-closing activity).  Are you testing on a device? which one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use onCreate() method to load your data and onDestroy() method to save data:

```
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       loadvars();
  }

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      savevars();
}
```

You can use too: onResume() with onPause() method but this two method are reserved for process (start process in onResume() method, stop process in onPause() method)

Comment: @omnisius: It is important to know the life cycle of an activity ;)

Comment: yes, you are right ! I just didn't think about it haha ! Good day to you and thank you again for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the savevars() method each time your activity is created. That means for sure every time your application starts.

In this method you are writing always the same value in the preferences:

```
edit.putString("gimli", Global.MAJ);
edit.commit();
```